# HANA While Loop

Tags: sql, while-loop, hana

I have a requirement and I think a possible solution, but I wanted to validate it first to ensure its the best approach.

There is currently a view that needs 2 new fields added. The first field will be spread in such a way that no day has more than 24 in it. The allocation will begin on the start date and continue each calendar day until the hours required are fully consumed. A new date entry will be made for each day the machine is in use.

So for example a machine requires 80 hours to finish a part. The new output will create 4 identical records except for the new date and hours required fields, as shown below.

| Date | Hours required |
| --- | --- |
| June 1 | 24 |
| June 2 | 24 |
| June 3 | 24 |
| June 4 | 8 |

My thoughts were to create a table function and use a while loop to continuously check the current field that has the required hours and check if its greater than 0 and subtract 24 until it was less than 24 in which that would be the final entry. It would also increment the start date by 1 day each time it went through the loop. I would then put the table function in a graphical view and then the front end could consume it.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 24 is constant or not? Is it the same for all the data or could vary on dates (for ex in Sundays it cannot be more than 5)? I hope it can also be achieved in graphical way, but loop is possible solution since HANA have no recursive CTE

Comment: For now 24 hours is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose your table has below structure :

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE "MachineCapacityHrs"( 
"Machine"  nvarchar(10),
"TotalHoursRequired" int,
"StartDate"   date
)
```

then you can generate date and hours required using below statement in ur table function without using loops :

```
select e."Machine",e."TotalHoursRequired",e."StartDate", 
t.date_sql as "DateSequence" ,
case when e."EndDate"<>t.date_sql then 24 else "Hrs" end as "HrsRequired"
from
(   select "Machine","TotalHoursRequired","StartDate",
    add_days("StartDate",case when floor("TotalHoursRequired"/24)=0 then 0
            else floor("TotalHoursRequired"/24) end
        ) as "EndDate",
    floor("TotalHoursRequired"/24) as "Days", 
    mod("TotalHoursRequired",24) as "Hrs",
    case when mod("TotalHoursRequired",24) >0 then floor("TotalHoursRequired"/24)+1 else floor("TotalHoursRequired"/24) end as "DateCount"
    from "MachineCapacityHrs" 
)e left outer join ( select date_sql from _sys_bi.m_time_dimension
)t on  t.date_sql  between e."StartDate" and e."EndDate"
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuK3A.png)

Comment: excuse the spacing :)